# CSS - Logo image stretched out of position only in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, responsive-design

I have a particle-slider effect for a logo on a site which transitions to a flat logo image file for screen sizes less than 960px. It works fine on Safari and chrome but on Firefox the image stretches out of shape.

**Safari/Chrome**

[image: Chrome/Safari]

**Firefox**
[image: Firefox]

Do I need to add some specific code for Firefox to make this work?

Here's how I have the code at the moment -

**style.css**

```
/* RWD for logo */

@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {


    #particle-slider {
        display: none;
    }   

}


@media screen and (min-width: 960px) {

     #logo img {

        display: none;
    } 

}


@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 960px) {

                #logo {

                    height: auto;

                }

                  #logo img {

                    width: 70%;
                    height: 30%;
                    position: relative;
                    top: 50px;
                    padding-bottom: 50px;
                    left: 15%;

                  }


}

/* ----------------------------------------- */
```

**particle-slider.php**

```
<?php /* Template Name: particle-slider */ ?>
<!-- particle-slider template -->

    <div id="particle-slider">
        <div class="slides">
            <div class="slide" data-src="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/havoc_logohight.png"></div>
        </div>
        <canvas class="draw" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></canvas>
     </div>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        var ps = new ParticleSlider({ 'width':'1400', 'height': '600' });
    </script>
  <div id="logo"> <img src="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/havoc_logo.png"> </div>

  <!-- particle-slider template -->
```

This has only appeared as an issue after I loaded the front-end files onto a Wordpress CMS (I'm using a HTML5 Blank Child theme), they worked fine as a stand-alone front-end site. How do I fix this?

Comment: Since the problem was not present in your standalone prototype, and only presented in your WP theme, it seems likely that the theme's styles are responsible. I would debug this by using FF's debugger to selectively disable any theme styles that are being applied to the img and its parents until you find the declaration that is causing the problem.

Comment: @JonathanNicol I've checked the console and nothing leapt out at me that was as a result of the theme, also I put something in the functions.php file that should have prevented this but I'll take your guidance on board and follow this through.

Comment: Another thing to try is removing the `height: 30%` style from the img. I am guessing you want the image to retain its aspect ratio so `height: auto` might work better?

Comment: @JonathanNicol Perfect - that worked. If you put it up as an answer I'll mark it as correct. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to hear that did the trick! I have added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try is removing the `height: 30%` style from the `img`. I am guessing you want the image to retain its aspect ratio so `height: auto` might work better?